# How do you determine the distance from a projected point and its point of projection on a sphere having a unit radius

Tags: differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, spherical-coordinates, spheres, riemann-sphere

Let a sphere with a unit radius lie on the x-y plane, centered (touching) the point zero.   Let a single point be somewhere on the surface of the sphere, but we can only see its projected point on the x-y plane. Given the values x(t) (its distance on the x axis), y(t) (its distance on the y axis), rho(t) (its radius on the x-y plane) and t (the angle of the point from the x axis), what is z(t) (the distance from the x-y plane to the point on the sphere)?

There should be two solutions, one for when a point is on the top half of the sphere and one when its on the bottom half, as both will project to the same place on the x-y plane.

Unknowns: r(t), the actual point P and z(t).

View this image for more details:

[Geometric representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNmVQ.jpg)

Comment: Could be missing something, but a point on the sphere is a distance $1$ away from the origin. So you should be able to use the formula $r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$ and solve for $z$.

Comment: r^2 is unknown though, so is z^2.

Comment: In the formula I just posted, $r=1,$ because you're dealing with a point *on the surface of the unit sphere*.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying.  But re-read and look at the image.  The sphere has a radius equal to one, but it is lying on the x-y plane, so each point is not 1 distance away from zero.  The point touching has the distance zero and the farthest has the distance 2.

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case, your formula changes to $1=x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2.$

Comment: That's exactly correct.  I checked with several arguments and matched it up geometrically.  Could you write up a short but formal answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the point is on a unit sphere, its distance from the center will be $1$. And since the equation of the surface of the sphere is $1=x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2,$ the correct solution for $z$ will be
$$z=1\pm\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}.$$